# I am trying to remove items from a list based upon items from another list (inside a loop). error: list index out of range

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
print('oc before remove',oc)
print('remlist before remove', remlist)

for i in range(len(remlist)):
    for j in range(len(oc)):
        if ( (remlist[i][0] == oc[j][0]) and (remlist[i][1] == oc[j][1]) ):
            del oc[j]

print('oc after remove', oc)
```

'oc' is de list from which I want to remove items that also occur in 'remlist'. My `prints` output the following:

```
('oc before remove', [[0, 0, 0]])
('remlist before remove', [[0, 0, 0]])
('oc after remove', [])
('oc before remove', [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]])
('remlist before remove', [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]])
```

Here the error occurs.

So the first time it succeeds, but the second time the following error is given:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand the meaning of this error, but I don't see why this error occurs here. I use the length of both lists to loop. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Side note: looks like you are using Python 2, where `print` is a statement. Don't try to use it as a function, you are printing tuples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you change the size of the list during iteration. Which obviously is a problem since after deleting a few items your `j` loop variable is going to be outside the range of the new (after deletion) list length. The first time it only works because the list only contains 1 element.

Try this instead:

```
oc = [item for item in oc if item not in remlist]
```

This list comprehension will keep the items from `oc` that are not in `remlist`.

Answer (score 2):

As you have deleted one element from oc during the runtime thats why it will give `IndexError: list index out of range`, oc[1] element will be missing.

I handel the case using `while loop`.

```
>>>oc =  [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
>>>remlist = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
for i in range(len(remlist)):
    j = 0
    while j <len(oc):
        if ( (remlist[i][0] == oc[j][0]) and (remlist[i][1] == oc[j][1]) ):
            del oc[j]
            j = j-1

        j = j+1
```

Result :

```
>>>oc
[[0, 1, 1]]
>>>remlist
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`len(oc)` is only evaluated once when you enter the loop, but after one iteration you remove an element and therefor the length of the list is changed. On the next iteration you are trying to access `oc[1][0]`, but at this point oc only has 1 element and therefor throws an exception.

Also note that you only compare the first 2 elements in each element (which in your example contain 3 elements each).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you delete items from a list while you are looping over it.
For lists of length 1 this will not give any problem, but anything longer than 1 will give problems, since the list becomes shorter while looping over it.

The thing is, in your second example, that beforehand you tell the loop to go over 2 items (since your list is of length 2). But if you find and remove an item, the list becomes smaller, and it will not be able to loop the full range that you set beforehand. I has become a list of length 1, and therefore you cannot access the second item.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:
1) Creating a new list and copying in it the elements that are in `oc` and not in `remlist`,
2) Deleting the elements that are in remlist directly from oc (in the case oc is big).

### Copying into a new list

```
res = []
for e in oc:
    if not e in remlist:
        res.append(e)
```

### Deleting directly from the list

Here, you can use remove.

```
for e in remlist:
    for i in xrange(oc.count(e)): oc.remove(e)
```

### Remark

I do not know why do you compare only the first and second elements of the sub-lists:

```
if ((remlist[i][0] == oc[j][0]) and (remlist[i][1] == oc[j][1])): ...
```

It is enough to write:

```
if (remlist[i] == oc[j]): ...
```

If you are sure of what you are doing, use at least:

```
if (remlist[i][0:2] == oc[j][0:2]): ...
```

It is more pythonic ;)